# How to get Graphviz to display diagram vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: python, graphviz

I am trying to use the Graphviz python package to display data, but it is not generating the diagram the way I would like.

[image: Current diagram output]

I would like the diagram to display as such:

```
Node A --> Node 1

Node B --> Node 2

Node C --> Node 3
```

Here is the code I currently have. The reason for the loops is because the data visualization needs to be scalable.

```
    list_a = ['nodeA','nodeB','nodeC']
    list_1 = ['node1','node2','node3']

    g = Digraph('G', filename='test.gv', format='png')

    for x,y,z in zip(list_a, list_1,range(len(list_a))):
        g.attr('node', shape='box', style = 'filled', fillcolor = 'lightgrey')
        g.node('node' + str(2*z), label = list_a[z])
        g.node('node' + str((2*z)+1), label = list_1[z])
        g.edge('node' + str(2*z), 'node' + str((2*z)+1))`
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the python package but usual you control the direction with the graph attribute rankdir it can have one of the values "TB", "LR", "BT", "RL"

see also

- https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:rankdir
- https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#k:rankdir

I would gues the following will do it:

```
    g.attr('graph', rankdir='TB')
```